# Formula for Sum and Product of Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then according to several sources, and my own derivation, the sum of the roots is $\frac{-b}{a}$ and the product is $\frac{c}{a}$. The problem I am working is the following:

> The equation $x^2 + ax - b = 0$ has equal roots, and one of the roots of the equation $x^2 + ax + 15 = 0$ is $3$. What is the value of $b$?
>
> A. -64
>
> B. -16
>
> C. -15
>
> D. -1/16
>
> E. -1/64

So, for the first equation, if $r$ denotes the roots, the sum should be $2r = -a$ and the product should be $r^2 = -b$...But this should immediately imply $b = 0$,  which is strangely missing from the choices above. I know it is late where I am, but I couldn't be making such an idiotic mistake...The product of the roots is the ratio of the constant term , in this case $-b$, to the coefficient of the leading term, which is $1$; thus, the product should be $\frac{-b}{1} = -b$...so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that $r^2=-b$ implies $b=0$? Could it not be e.g. -4?

Comment: @Nick That was precisely my problem. For some odd reason, I began with the presupposition that $b$ is negative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the equation $x^2 + ax - b = 0$ has equal roots, then it must be of the form $(x - r)^2 = x^2 - 2xr + r^2$ for some $r.$ Thus, we know that $a = -2r$ and $b = -r^2$ for some $r.$ You got this far yourself.

We know that one of the roots of $x^2 + ax + 15 = 0$ is 3, so plugging in $x = 3$ should give a true statement. Thus, we know that $9 + 3a + 15 = 0,$ so $a = -8.$ This gives us that $r = 4,$ and so $b = -16.$

Your answer is B.

EDIT: The mistake you were making was assuming that $r^2 = -b$ implies that $b = 0.$ I'm not really sure where you got this from. The crux of the solution was realizing that $x = 3$ must be a root of $x^2 + ax + 15.$

Comment: In response to the remark in your edit: probably because I was being an idiotic by thinking $b$ had to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the Vieta theorem. The second condition implies $3a+24=0$, which gives us $a=-8$. Since the equation $x^2-8a-b=0$ has equal roots, the left-hand side is a perfect square. This is only possible when $x^2-8a-b=(x-4)^2$, that is, when $b=-16$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x) = x^{2}+ax-b =0 $

and $g(x) = x^{2}+ax+15 =0$

Let's define $\alpha: f(\alpha) = 0$

We also have $g(3) = 0$

Let's define $\beta: g(\beta) = 0$

$g(x) = (x-3)(x-\beta) = = x^{2} -(3+\beta)x + 3\beta = x^{2}+ax+15$

Comparing coefficients, we get:

$3\beta = 15 \Rightarrow \beta = 5$

$3+\beta = 8 = -a \Rightarrow a = -8$

Then $f(x) = x^{2}-8x -b = (x-\alpha)^{2} = x^{2} -2\alpha x +\alpha ^{2} =0$

Again, comparing coefficients:

$-2\alpha = -8 \Rightarrow \alpha = 4$

$-b = \alpha^{2} = 16 \Rightarrow b=-16$